# How to: Add items on the same line in a TreeView in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, treeview

I want to add a TreeViewItem and some other controls to the right of the TreeViewItem on the same line next to the header. I want the other controls to be visible without having to expand the item as well. Comment with any questions and I'll try to answer them. Thanks, seeker.

P.S. Thought I had found an answer earlier, but I was wrong. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give it a blind shot:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItemHeader>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock>Header text</TextBlock>
                <Button>Some other button</Button> <!-- this is `some other control -->
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItemHeader>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

It's not that clear what do you want to achieve, maybe a mockup?

Comment: That works. Excellent job! I think that'll even be easier than going with what I was going to do. I was going to build a user control. I'm a bit new to Silverlight and haven't reached the point of realizing I can use other container controls instead. The StackPanel is another life saver.